# How can I use a global PHP file to keep track of whether or not the user is logged in?

Tags: php, constants, global, status

I'm working on a simple web app with PHP and MySQL. I'm very new to both technologies. I was thinking of making a class or just a "top" file that can keep track of variables like IsLoggedIn that are either 0 or 1 depending on whether or not the user is logged in. I want to do this because some pages will display different content or no content depending on whether or not the user is logged in.

At first, I was thinking of creating a BasePage class that every single class inherits from, and then modifying a variable in BasePage after the user logs in and logs out. That variable can be my "toggle" that keeps track of the user's current state. Is it better to do this via some file named constants.php that just defines constants and lets me access the constants in all my other files? Or is creating a BasePage class a better practice?

I'm open to any other suggestions as well. Thanks. Here is a sample of the BasePage class that I was thinking of building:

```
<?php
class BasePage
{
    public $loggedIn = false;

    public function ToggleLogingStatus(){
        $loggedIn = !$loggedIn;
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Well, a global PHP file can't keep track of whether the user is logged in or not just by itself. You need to either use sessions or cookies (or both in combination). Just google "php loginscript" and you will get enough tutorials and examples. Maybe you even want to take a look at a php framework like Laravel.

Comment: I'll check out sessions, that sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and thank you again. Sessions are perfect! :) Please write an answer so I can accept it, assuming you want the reputation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple PHP file can't keep track of a users login statement without any medium. A solution to that problem is either using PHP sessions or cookies. Just keep in mind to check all user inputs. Don't trust any user inputs, cookies, sessions (the client sends a cookie and the server grabs the session for that cookie in the backend), variables coming from the client.

For the start sessions would do their job, but maybe later on you want to do more and switch over to your own session management with cookies. Maybe then you get to the point where a PHP framework would be useful and beneficial. Some examples would be Laravel, Yii and Zend Framework.

tl;dr: Until you make big applications use sessions and google for some loginscript tutorials. Just keep in mind to use PDO with Prepared Statements to communicate with any database, so you won't get into crossfire of SQL Injections.

Comment: How is mysqli instead of PDO? Would it be better to just transition into using PDO while I'm still new to mysqli?

Comment: Well, MySQLi is fine. But it's just an extension for MySQL. So you can't use it for any other databases (Mongo, PostgreSQL, MSSQL...). PDO has a better integration of Prepared Statements and I recommend to use PDO instead of MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

I have a web app that also has protected pages. All of my pages require a sort of base page that has MySQL connection variables, frequently used functions and classes, etc.

In this page, I have a function called protectedPage(); This function checks the user's logged in status. At the top of every protected page, this function gets called. So...

```
<?php
require_once('/home/ubuntu/keypage/base_page.php');
protectedPage();
// Rest of code
?>
```

That sits on top of all of my protected pages. The function checks for sessions and all other useful user info, like the user level, if need be.

Hope that helps.